# How to publish OOS(Office Online Servers) via nginx?

Tags: windows, nginx, iis

How to publish OOS(Office Online Servers) via nginx?

available:

1. Deployed on an internal Exchange 2016 network with port 443 forwarded to the outside.
2. Windows Server with OOS installed

3.nginx

```
server {
    listen extip:80;
    server_name oos.example.com www.oos.example.com;
    location / {
            access_log /var/log/nginx/oos.example.com-http-access.log custom;
            return 301 https://oos.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl proxy_protocol;
    server_name oos.example.com www.oos.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/oos.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/oos.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/oos.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;

    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    real_ip_header proxy_protocol;

    location / {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/oos.example.com-https-access.log custom;
        proxy_pass https://192.168.0.2;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

1. From the Internet I go to https://oos.example.com/hosting/discovery everything is fine, the XML page opens.
2. From the Internet, I go to OWA and try to preview the xls file, in the preview area the following message: The site oos.example.com does not allow you to establish a connection.
3. On a machine on the local network (I added to the hosts file: 192.168.0.2 oos.example.com ), the preview works.

I ask for help or advice from those who have solved a similar problem.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

**delete** X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN from iis or/and proxy